# Android heap dump too small

Tags: android, ddms, hprof

I am trying to get heap dump for android application (lots of UI tests with leakage and so on) consuming near 160Mb (seen in logs and in ddms) - but getting heap hprof file which is only 50Mb size.

Trying to open it in Android Studio or MAT results in error:

> Unexpected error while processing hprof file: null

Or hprof-conv

> ERROR: read N of M bytes